# SQL Join SELECT MAX, But also where a value does not exist

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following SQL which works - It displays all of the items, along with the MAX starttime.

However, I'd also like to show items that to not have a record in playlistlog - How would one

```
SELECT items.idx, items.title, items.artist, playlistlog.starttime
FROM items
LEFT JOIN playlistlog ON playlistlog.item = items.idx
WHERE playlistlog.starttime = (
    SELECT MAX(starttime)
    FROM playlistlog AS pl2
    WHERE pl2.item = items.idx
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `where` clause is turning your left join into an inner join.

Use `AND` instead of `WHERE`.

```
SELECT items.idx, items.title, items.artist, playlistlog.starttime
FROM items
LEFT JOIN playlistlog ON playlistlog.item = items.idx
and playlistlog.starttime = (
    SELECT MAX(starttime)
    FROM playlistlog AS pl2
    WHERE pl2.item = items.idx
)
```

Comment: You learn something new everyday - Thank you, that's done the job perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done a bit shorter using standard SQL's window function:

```
SELECT items.idx, items.title, items.artist, pl.starttime
FROM items
  LEFT JOIN (
    select item, 
           starttime, 
           row_number() over (partition by item order by starttime desc) as rn
    from playlistlog
  ) pl ON pl.item = items.idx AND pl.rn = 1
```